# Linear Transformation mapping linearly independent vectors onto a linearly dependent set

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear transformation. Show that if
$T$ maps two linearly independent vectors onto a linearly dependent set, then the equation $T($**x**$)=$**0** has a nontrivial solution.

Proof. Suppose **u** and **v** are linearly independent but T(**u**) and T(**v**) are linearly dependent. Then $c_1T($**u**$)+c_2T($**v**$)$ = **0** where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are not equal to 0

Since $T$ is linear, $T(c_1$**u**$+c_2$**v**$)$=**0**. Now, $x=c_1$**u**$+c_2$**v** cannot be **0** because **u** and **v** are linearly independent. Therefore, $T($**x**$)$=**0**.

Is this proof correct? How could I make it more straightforward?

Comment: The proof is correct and I don't believe there is much that can be made more straightforward. Just a few things about precise notation: When you say that $c_1 T(u) + c_2T(v)=0$ you should say: "there are some $c_1, c_2$ which are not both equal to zero with $c_1T(u) + c_2T(v)=0$". In the end when saying $c_1u+c_2v \ne 0$ you are implicitely using that $c_1 =  c_2=0$ is not the case without writing it down. But the idea of your proof is entirely correct.

Comment: In addition to @Lukas comment, I think you should rephrase a bit of your third paragraph. It's not really clear how you come to  $T(c1u+c2v)=0$ and I really don't understand why do you say it implies that $T(0)=0$? All in all, I think you got the idea for the proof, you just need a to be a bit more precise in your notations.

Comment: Edited @F.Carette